# How can I properly mock a Principal object in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, mockito

First of all, I have the following endpoint method present within a class called **RecipeController**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/recipes"})
    public String listRecipes(Model model, Principal principal){
        List<Recipe> recipes;
        User user = (User)((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)principal).getPrincipal();
        User actualUser = userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if(!model.containsAttribute("recipes")){
            recipes = recipeService.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("nullAndNonNullUserFavoriteRecipeList",
                    UtilityMethods.nullAndNonNullUserFavoriteRecipeList(recipes, actualUser.getFavoritedRecipes()));

            model.addAttribute("recipes", recipes);
        }

        if(!model.containsAttribute("recipe")){
            model.addAttribute("recipe", new Recipe());
        }

        model.addAttribute("categories", Category.values());
        model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        return "recipe/index";
    }
```

As you can see above, the method takes as a second parameter a **Principal** object. When running the application, the parameter points to a non-null object as expected. It contains information about the user that is currently logged in within the application.

I have created a test class for the **RecipeController** called **RecipeControllerTest**. This class contains a single method called **testListRecipes**.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RecipeControllerTest{

    @Mock
    private RecipeService recipeService;

    @Mock
    private IngredientService ingredientService;

    @Mock
    private StepService stepService;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal;

    private RecipeController recipeController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        recipeController = new RecipeController(recipeService,
                ingredientService, stepService, userService);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(recipeController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testListRecipes() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();

        List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        recipes.add(recipe);

        when(principal.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(user);
        when(userService.findByUsername(anyString()))
                .thenReturn(user);
        when(recipeService.findAll()).thenReturn(recipes);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/recipes"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("recipe/index"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("recipes"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("recipe"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("categories"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("username"));

        verify(userService, times(1)).findByUsername(anyString());
        verify(recipeService, times(1)).findAll();
    }
}
```

As you can see in this second snippet, I tried to mock the **Principal** object within the test class, using the **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken** implementation.

When I run the test, I get a **NullPointerException**, and the stacktrace points me to the following line from the first snippet of code:

```
User user = (User)((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)principal).getPrincipal();
```

The principal object passed as a parameter to the **listRecipes** method from is still null, even though I tried to provide a mock object.

**Any suggestions ?**

Comment: To start with, use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` and don't do your several unsafe casts in your controller. Then just construct a real, actual `UserDetails` instance and pass it to the controller. When using MockMvc, you need to read the documentation on Spring Security integration (which requires adding it to the `standaloneSetup`), and you should use something like `@WithUserDetails` on your test method.

Comment: @chrylis Using `@AuthenticationPrincipal User user` as the second parameter instead of `Principal principal` and commenting out the `user` variable from within the controller method did the trick for me. The `User` class implements the `UserDetails` interface, as you specified above. There is no exception thrown anymore. Please create an answer with your comment, in order for me to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC is very flexible with controller arguments, which lets you put most of the responsibility of looking up information onto the framework and focus on writing the business code. In this particular case, while you *can* use `Principal` as a method parameter, it's usually much better to use your actual principal class:

```
public String listRecipes(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user)
```

To actually set the user for a test, you need to work with Spring Security, which means adding `.apply(springSecurity())` to your setup. (Complications like this, by the way, are the main reason I dislike using `standaloneSetup`, as it requires you to remember to duplicate your exact production setup. I recommend writing actual unit tests and/or full-stack tests.) Then annotate your test with `@WithUserDetails` and specify the username of the test user.

Finally, as a side note this controller pattern can be simplified significantly with Querydsl, as Spring is able to inject a `Predicate` that combines all of the filter attributes you're looking up by hand, and then you can pass that predicate to a Spring Data repository.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that implements `Principal`:

```
class PrincipalImpl implements Principal {

    @Override
    public String getName() {

        return "XXXXXXX";
    }

}
```

Sample test:

```
@Test
public void login() throws Exception {
    Principal principal = new PrincipalImpl();

    mockMvc.perform(get("/login").principal(principal)).andExpect(.........;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using...?

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "my_principal")
public void testListRecipes() {
...
```

Comment: I tried using that annotation. But didn't really help me in this case.